# Windows For command Fails for files over 2gb

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, command

I have a windows for /F command that works perfectly well on files up to 2gb but simply does nothing and proceeds to the next command when they are over 2gb

I have searched for documentation regarding a limit but I can not find any - can anyone confirm that this is a real limit?

Assuming that it is I need to copy a file deleting the top three lines - any ideas (the for command is pretty slow anyway).

Comment: It may help to know what version of Windows you are using and what is the file system of the volume on which these files reside.

Comment: Im pretty sure that it does have a 2GB limit.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I believe `for /F` has a 2GB limit.  I think your best bet is to use `sed` from gnuwin32.  Google for gnuwin32 sed and click the first result.  Download the binaries zip file and extract the contents of the bin folder somewhere in your path.

The appropriate command is as follows:

```
sed "1,3d" oldfile > newfile
```

This should be much faster than a batch `for` loop anyway.